# Cannot connect to Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have integrated Kafka support into our server and tested it. It runs fine in my developer environment, but other developers cannot get it running in their developer environment. The problem is similar to what I have experience in my own developer environment, but I cannot understand why it works on my machine and not theirs.

Basically we run Kafka in a docker-compose stack. In both environments `docker-compose ps` shows the same configuration running.

```
$ docker-compose ps
           Name                           Command               State                         Ports                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
localdockerdevelop_kafka-1_1     start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                             
localdockerdevelop_kafka-2_1     start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9093->9092/tcp                             
localdockerdevelop_kafka-3_1     start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9094->9092/tcp                             
localdockerdevelop_mysql_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                             
localdockerdevelop_redis_1       docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                             
localdockerdevelop_zookeeper_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

In both environments if you `telnet 127.0.0.1 9092` you connect to the Kafka broker. However, in their environment when the Kafka Admin client attempts to connect to `bootstrap.servers= "127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.1:9093,127.0.0.1:9094"` it times out, but for my environment it connects immediately. We're both running from our `develop` branch in Git, so we should be running identical environments.

Another test: I have my docker-compose stack running on my machine, and when I run our server it connects fine. When my colleague configures his bootstrap.servers to use my ip-address he sees the same problem, even though he can telnet to the broker on my machine.

Can anyone suggests any other diagnostic tips and tricks to figure out why the Kafka Admin Client cannot connect to a broker?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the problem. I was following the examples at https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker and tried to take the easy path of using KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME. Kafka has deprecated advertised.host.name and trying to use it in a multi-broker configuration is problematic.

Earlier I got around the problem by adding broker hostnames to /etc/hosts and this kludge works, but I **forgot** I was using the kludge and did not tell the other developers. The team does not want to have to edit /etc/hosts, so I am working on a solution that does not involve advertised.host.name